# how to write a command on linux

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I have to implement a linux command, called DCMD, which has the following function: It must execute another default linux command to a certain date and time, both specified in input.

In short, I should write like this: `dcmd "command" "date and time"`.

Well the problem is not date or hour, in fact I can manage it properly, if it is looking into the future, if the day, month and year are correct, etc. ..
Also the command I think I've figured out how to handle it: I used the system call "execlp" and it run properly.

Well, at this point I don't know how to merge command and data, that is, run the following command at the time indicated.

Could someone explain to me how to do?

Comment: Why would you want to do this when `cron` already exists?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to reimplement the `at` command.

Comment: There's a command called `at` which already does this.

Comment: you can download at source code and look into it, on distros using apt it could be as simple as `apt-get source at`....

Comment: Thanks, but I have to reimplement those commands. Do I have to write a script?

Comment: The order of the arguments is not very convenient. If it would be  `dcmd 'date and time ' cmd args ...` it would allow you to use any command, with any number of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

On linux, use `cron` or `at` to schedule jobs for later running.

**cron**: Specify a cron job with your specific date. Format your command as `minute hour day month ? year  command` and add it to your crontab file. `cron` will then run your job just once. Use `crontab` to handle your crontab file. [Man page for crontab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab)

**at command**: Syntax: `at [-V] [-q queue] [-f file] [-mldbv] TIME`  to run the script on stdin at `TIME`. Alternatively, run script in a file with the `-f` flag. [Man page for at](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at)

Comment: Thanks, but I have to reimplement those commands. Do I have to write a script?

Answer (score 0):

**Additional information**:This is a Operating System assignment in which I have to re-implement some of the features of "at" or "crontab".

I have found a way of how to solve this problem.

First of all I should call a "fork", then in the child process I should call the "execlp", while the parent process goes on.

If I want to delay the command, I'll call a "sleep" in the child process (I asked about this point to the professor a few days ago, and he said that it's fine).

But I have this question: is it a valid method? Does this method create zombie processes?